# Anylogic - Using String Value to get an Object

Tags: java, object, anylogic

I have a text object (Shape text) in the Main tab. Right now I am referring the text value by hard coding the name in the areas wherever I use.

I want to add more text objects like text1, text2 etc. which properly follows a pattern for the suffix numbers. I have a variable for count of text objects.

In a function, I want to go through all these text object values using a loop. I am able to generate Strings of "text1", "text2", "text3", etc. using simple for loop.

I want to know how to refer these objects and get the values in the text objects.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

what you can instead, is create a collection (arraylist) that contains all these text objects, if they are ordered in the list the way you want, you can use the index of that collection as your identifier..

```
collection.get(index);
```

If you insist in using the name, you can make a collection of type LinkedHashMap where the key element class is String and the value elements class is ShapeText

Then you can know what the text is by using
`collection.get("text1");` for instance